# Popping back stack twice causes an error

Tags: java, android, back-stack

I have fragments that have been added to the back stack in this order:

1. Target Fragment (could be one of two fragments)
2. InfoFragment
3. SuccessFragment

SuccessFragment has a button that has an onClick() which looks like this:

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                activity.getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                activity.getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
```

However, doing the `popBackStack()` twice results in an error stating that InfoFragment is not attached to an activity. How can I properly pop the back stack twice without this error?

EDIT: Added code for how fragments are added to backstack.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment, new InfoFragment());
                        transaction.addToBackStack(getResources().getString(R.string.tag_info_fragment));
                        transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Can you show how you add fragments to the backstack?

Comment: I found these methods in abstract class FragmentManager
 public abstract Fragment getFragment(Bundle var1, String var2);
public abstract FragmentManager.BackStackEntry getBackStackEntryAt(int var1); but I never used them so can't give you exact solution. But as FragementManager works as Stack implementation you can not pop element when its empty or pop for same element twice unless you add same fragment twice

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin Added code for adding to backstack above.

Comment: hard to suggest something.. are you sure you add both fragments to backstack? Take a look at `fm.getBackStackEntryCount()` to see if that's correct. As I understand you correctly, when you do first `popBackStack()` you see previous fragment on a screen, but when you do one more `popBackStack` it says that fragment is not attached?

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin So, both popBackStacks happen, seemingly, instantly. After that button is clicked, I see the TargetFragment visibly, then the error gets through that InfoFragment is not attached to an activity.

Comment: What happens if you change `popBackStack()` to `popBackStackImmediate()`?

Comment: @krislarson Had the same though. Same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, using popBackStack twice turns out not to be the issue. The issue was an async call in InfoFragment's onStart method that I did not consider. The async call was in the onStart method, which, when popBackStack was called, was also called. This async called completed after the second popBackStack had removed the InfoFragment. This async call was a URI loaded image, and since the fragment was no longer attached to an activity, the attempt to set the ImageView's image failed.